# "Centering" mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to make a photo gallery in  php + mysql.

The URL viewphoto.php?id=143 shows photo 143.
In the navigation menu, I want to display the previous two photos in that album, and the next two.

I thought of using:

```
$temp_id = $id - 2;
mysql_query("SELECT id, photo FROM photos WHERE album = {$album} AND id >= {$temp_id} LIMIT 5");
```

But that didn't work, because photo's from different albums could have the ids preceding and succeeding the one of the viewed photo.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to define "previous" and "next" first. **In terms your database comprehends.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been dealing with this issue myself and I never found an elegant solution to the problem, I ended up doing it in two queries:

```
// next
mysql_query("SELECT id, photo FROM photos WHERE album = {$album} AND id > {$id} ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2");

// prev
mysql_query("SELECT id, photo FROM photos WHERE album = {$album} AND id <= {$id} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Now the first item in "prev" once fetched would be the current photo.

This solution does has to be amended with a check that the first item in "prev" is in fact the requested id, because it doesn't make sure it's the proper id, in case of gaps in the series.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. With an UNION between these two queries it's exactly what I were looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, a union would give a nice array! But would it relieve the DB server any?

Answer (score 6):

Using the id to sort your pictures is a bad idea. Imagine you delete one picture. Your chain of pictures will be broken. In order to fix it, you would need to change the id column, which is an even worse idea.

Either use a seperate index column for the sorting within one album. This index could be rebuilt easily in the case of a picture getting deleted.

Or you define a "previous" and "next" column in your table. This would then contain the id of the last and next picture. If a picture gets deleted, you only need to change these columns for the previous and the next picture.

With both methods, you could for example use a nested self join to access your previous and next 2 pictures. Comment on this post if you need help on that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm making an extra sorting column. That'll do it.

Comment: @Before though nothing bad in using id as long as it's order suits you. If you delete a picture it will break nothing. You need separate field only if you want to change the order manually.